# Using v-tooltip on custom (non native) component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a custom component which is being used application wide. But, in some place I want to show tooltip on hover on this component, according to vuetify docs this should work but it doesn't because `<custom-component />` is not a native component.
And to have this functionality for native component a `.native` modifier is to be used.

Example: `@click.native="someMethod"`
How can I do that to show v-tooltip.

I have tried wrapping `<custom-component />` in a div but it isn't working.

Below is sample code to get the gist.

```html
<v-tooltip>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <custom-component v-on="on" />
  </template>
  <span>Tooltip text</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Comment: Very hard to answer without code example (Your Q is too general) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`custom-component` should forward events from an element with `v-on="$listeners"`
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

> I have tried wrapping `<custom-component />` in a div but it isn't working

If you do this then the events need to be bound to the div instead:

```html
<div v-on="on">
  <custom-component />
</div>
```